# Can't run R on Mac

Tags: r

I'm trying to download R on my mac. I have Big Sur and a M1 chip.

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: switch(os, Linux = if (file.exists("/etc/os-release")) {
  error: EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

Comment: You need to give more details.  Where did you download it from?  Which file did you download?

Comment: I downloaded from the RStudio website. https://cran.rstudio.com/index.html

Comment: Did you download it from the link [Download R for macOS](https://cran.rstudio.com/index.html)? Did you download the "Big Sur" version listed as the Apple silicon arm64 build (i.e. an M1 chip Mac)?

Comment: Yes I downloaded the big sur version a couple of times

Comment: These just appear to be warning messages - are you not able to run commands? What does `version` give you? Or `sessionInfo()`?